# Creating SSRS report using C# code behind

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am creating SSRS report using code behind C# not from tool.
  i want to add 
      rd:UserDefined true 
 tag with query parameter using C# code behind. How can i add this tag from my code to dataset as it is giving xml error.

My code to add queryParameter is :

```
XmlElement queryParameters;
    XmlElement queryParameter;

    queryParameters = AddElement(query, "QueryParameters", null);

    queryParameter = AddElement(queryParameters, "QueryParameter", null);
    AddAttribute(queryParameter, doc, "Name", "@ReportID");
    AddElement(queryParameter, "Value", _objDynamicProcedureParameters.ReportID);
    AddElement(queryParameter, "rd:UserDefined", "true");
```

I want to add queryParameter which should be shown on reportviewer as filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this.

Added Reportparameters tag to add report parameters just like this :

```
  ReportParameter = AddElement(ReportParameters, "ReportParameter", null);
  AddAttribute(ReportParameter, doc, "Name", "RoleName");
  AddElement(ReportParameter, "DataType", "String");
```